# Checkbox content IE 11/Edge

Tags: html, css, checkbox, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I face a problem with `checkbox` in IE and Edge, namely a "content" class. I have the following code:

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-edit-article" name="breakingNews" ng-model="showPublished" ng-change="updateCategory(selectedCategory, pageID)">
    <label for="checkbox" class="checkbox-edit-article-label">
        Show only published articles
    </label>
</input>
```

When field is checked

```css
.checkbox-edit-article:checked + .checkbox-edit-article-label:before {
    content: url(../img/mark-white.png);
    background: rgb(49,119,61);
    color: #fff;
    height: 44px;
    line-height: 2.4;
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

and static

```css
.checkbox-edit-article + .checkbox-edit-article-label:before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 43px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px white;
}
```

In Chrome `content: url(../img/mark-white.png);` is displayed perfectly, but in IE this check image is too high because of `line-height`, but I don't know how to center the picture in the checkbox.

I ask your help, how I can align the image?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you give us enough to reproduce the problem? maybe a working fiddle, what do these images look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your image in `background` instead, like this

```
background: rgb(49,119,61) url(../img/mark-white.png) no-repeat center center;
```

Sample snippet

```css
.checkbox-edit-article:checked + .checkbox-edit-article-label:before {
  content: '';
  background: rgb(49,119,61) url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOQI7.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 25px 25px;  /* this I just added to make my bigger mark be small */
  color: #fff;
  height: 44px;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.checkbox-edit-article + .checkbox-edit-article-label:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px white;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-edit-article" name="breakingNews" ng-model="showPublished" ng-change="updateCategory(selectedCategory, pageID)">
<label for="checkbox" class="checkbox-edit-article-label">Show only published articles</label>
```